# Powershell delete folders -force

Tags: powershell

I cannot seem to remove files/folders without me having to enter [A] for all. What am I missing?

```
Get-Childitem "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
  Where {$_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).adddays(-7)} |
    Remove-Item -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false -Force
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `-recurse` to your `remove-item`.

Answer (score 2):

As [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) points out, **it is the `-Recurse` switch that is needed to suppress the *extra* confirmation prompt that is presented when `Remove-Item` is called to remove a *nonempty container* (directory).**

This ***extra* confirmation prompt** is specifically presented for the higher-risk operation of removing *containers along with their children* and is ***independent* of the *common* confirmation mechanism:**

- That is, neither the cmdlet's declared impact level, nor the presence of `-Confirm` or `-Confirm:$False`, nor the value of the `$ConfirmPreference` preference variable impact whether the *extra* prompt is shown.
- These elements do, however, as usual, control whether the *common* prompt is shown, so that if you pass 
  `-Confirm`, for instance, you'll get the common confirmation prompt *in addition* to the extra one, *after* the latter; in the case of a *non-container* item (file) or a container that happens to be *empty*, `-Confirm` will show *only* the common prompt.

Note:

***Typically*, such extra prompts are suppressed with the `-Force` switch**, as in the case of the 
`Set-ExecutionPolicy` cmdlet.

**In the context of `Remove-Item`, however, `-Force` has a different meaning**: it ensures that files or directories that are hidden or files that have the read-only attribute set can be deleted.

Therefore, it is **`-Recurse`** that **signals the explicit intent to remove a container *along with its content***, and thereby suppresses the extra prompt.