# Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt

Tags: powershell, ansible, confirmation, non-interactive, win-shell

```
     win_shell: | 
     Get-disk
     Initialize-Disk -Number 2 -PartitionStyle MBR
     clear-disk -number 2 -removedata -Confirm:$false
     Initialize-Disk -Number 2 -PartitionStyle MBR
     new-partition -disknumber 2 -usemaximumsize | format-volume -filesystem NTFS - 
     newfilesystemlabel Data -Force
     get-partition -disknumber 2 | set-partition -newdriveletter G
```

In the above code getting "Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt." I am executing the above code using ansible playbook. Manually it is getting executed but when executed through the ansible getting error. Please help!

Comment: I'm not ansible smart but creating disks is an Admin task.  What context is your 'win-shell' task running as (e.g. service account (with or without Admin privs)).  That'd be where I'd start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message implies that **your PowerShell code triggered an interactive *confirmation prompt***, which, **when PowerShell is running in *non-interactive* mode ([CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter `-NonInteractive`) fails by design**.<sup>[1]</sup>

For *some* of the commands you're already trying to *suppress* these prompts, with `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false`, but seemingly at least one of your commands still tries to prompt.

To **categorically suppress all confirmation prompts**<sup>[2]</sup> in a given script, you can use the [`$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues) as follows:

- **Caveat**: The following deliberately bypasses all confirmation prompts and forces actions that would be refused by default, **potentially destructive actions are *instantly* attempted - only use this technique if you're absolutely sure that the commands will work as intended**. Also, in some cmdlets `-Force` has semantics that are unrelated to confirmation prompts, such as *including hidden items* when used with `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Item`.
  In preparation, it's always a good idea to use the [common `-WhatIf` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) to *preview* what a command would otherwise do.

```sh
# !! SEE WARNING ABOVE.
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ '*:Force' = $true; '*:Confirm' = $false }

# ... Commands that normally prompt for confirmation.
```

Note:

- The above deliberately assigns a *new* [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) to an implicitly *local* `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable, so as to limit the settings to the current scope (and its descendants). While simply *adding to* / *modifying* the preexisting `$PSDefaultParameterValues` dictionary defined in the global scope (e.g. `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Force'] = $true`) is technically possible, the changes would then take effect *globally* and may affect unrelated scripts run later in the same session. (That said, in the context of deployment tools such as Ansible, where a given PowerShell process runs a specific piece of code only, this problem won't arise).
- In the rare event that you want to *preserve existing values* from the global dictionary, you can create a local *clone* of it first and then add to / modify that: `$PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()   $PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Force'] = $true   $PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Confirm'] = $false`

---

<sup>[1] Try `powershell -NonInteractive -Command 'Read-Host'`, for instance, to provoke the error.</sup>

<sup>[2] At least for those commands that use only the two standard mechanisms for allowing prompts to be suppressed, `-Confirm:$false` and `-Force`. A notable exception is `Remove-ChildItem`, which, when a nonempty directory is targeted, requires `-Recurse` in order to avoid a confirmation prompt - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55233452/45375).</sup>