# How can I disable Internet Explorer parsing in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

The `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet can fail if Internet Explorer is not available*:

```
The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.
```

If I'm on a computer that has a working Internet Explorer, `-UseBasicParsing` is not required. I want to test that my script will work on computers that either haven't run IE or where IE has been uninstalled. In my test environment, how can I deliberately create the conditions in which the above error will happen?

* Before PowerShell 6.0.0.

Answer (score 6):

> If I'm on a computer that has a working Internet Explorer, `-UseBasicParsing` is not required.

Even if it isn't *required* to avoid errors, you should use this switch, *unless* you truly need parsing the response into a DOM, accessible via the `.ParsedHTML` property.
`-UseBasicParsing` prevents the overhead resulting from this unnecessary parsing.

Thus, **if you don't need the Internet Explorer-mediated DOM parsing, *always* using 
`-UseBasicParsing` is fine, and even works in *cross-edition* scenarios**:
While `-UseBasicParsing` is *never needed* in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (v6+) - where parsing into a DOM isn't even *available* - you can still use it there, without ill effects.

---

If you want to avoid having to pass the `-UseBasicParsing` switch to *each and every call*, you can ***preset* `-UseBasicParsing` *session-wide*, via the [`$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues)**:

```bash
# Note: '*' targets *all* commands that have a -UseBasicParsing parameter
#       While you could 'Invoke-WebRequest' instead of '*',
#       '*' ensures that 'Invoke-RestMethod' is covered too.
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:UseBasicParsing'] = $true
```

**If you want to *scope* this preset to a *given script*** (and scripts / functions called from it), use the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71114231/45375).

---

> how can I deliberately create the conditions in which the above error will happen?

If you want to **run tests against your code that *simulate* the error condition**, so as to ensure that all your code uses `-UseBasicParsing`:

- Install the [Pester](https://github.com/Pester/Pester) module, e.g. with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser Pester`. Pester is a widely used test framework for PowerShell.
- Use Pester's *mocking* capabilities to simulate an error whenever an [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) or [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) call is made *without* `-UseBasicParsing`.

Here's a *simple* example (save to, say, `EnforceBasicParsing.Tests.ps1` and invoke with `.\EnforceBasicParsing.Tests.ps1`):

```bash
Describe 'Enforce -UseBasicParsing' {
  BeforeAll {
    # Set up mocks for Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod
    # that throw whenever -UseBasicParsing isn't passed.
    $exceptionMessageAndErrorId = "Missing -UseBasicParsing"
    'Invoke-WebRequest', 'Invoke-RestMethod' | ForEach-Object {
      Mock -CommandName $_  `
           -ParameterFilter { -not $UseBasicParsing } `
           -MockWith{ throw $exceptionMessageAndErrorId } 
    }
  }
  It 'Fails if -UseBasicParsing is NOT used with Invoke-WebRequest' {
    { Invoke-WebRequest http://example.org } |
      Should -Throw -ErrorId $exceptionMessageAndErrorId
  }
  It 'Fails if -UseBasicParsing is NOT used with Invoke-RestMethod' {
    { Invoke-RestMethod http://example.org } |
      Should -Throw -ErrorId $exceptionMessageAndErrorId
  }
  It 'Deliberately failing test' {
    { Invoke-RestMethod http://example.org } |
      Should -Not -Throw -ErrorId $exceptionMessageAndErrorId
  }
}
```

The first two tests succeed, whereas the third one is deliberately made to fail, showing what would happen if the test ran against real code not using `-UseBasicParsing`.

See also: the [Pester documentation](https://pester.dev/docs/quick-start).

Comment: This doesn't help me. I agree that I want to always use `-UseBasicParsing` argument. I'm looking for a way to ensure that I do that everywhere.

Comment: That's a really interesting edit, but it's *still* not quite what I'm asking.

My goal is "I want to test that my script will work on computers that either haven't run IE or where IE has been uninstalled."

My specific question is "how do I create these conditions, such that a bad script will fail?"

Comment: @JayBazuzi, see my update re testing using Pester.

Comment: Monkey patching might be the best I can do.